# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while running a program from eclipse jboss server. The same program when run as a standalone works fine

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am trying to use a third party library file. This library is loaded using the System.load("");
The list of all loaded libraries was retreived after this load and the dll file in question was loaded. When I run my program as standalone app it works fine. However, when it is invoked through our application (running on eclipse/ jboss server) I get the following exception.

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.opswat.metascan.MetascanInterface.initialize(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.opswat.metascan.MetascanInterface.initialize(Native Method)
    at com.opswat.metascan.MetascanInterface.(MetascanInterface.java:513)

VM Argument setting is verified. Not sure what is stopping jboss from recognizing a loaded library? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're using different class loaders for each your web application and your invoked application. Maybe you want/need to add the jar into the classpath of your invoked application.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We are using same class loaders and the jar is added to the classpath.